# PHP array of dates

Tags: php

Can anyone help me:
I have function `date_range` that returns all dates between 2 given dates.
This is a call of that function:

```
$date_array = date_range($ci,$co);
$dates = "\"" . implode("\",\"",$date_array) . "\"";
```

A function `setSpecificDate` recieves dates and makes them unselectable. When I call function with dates, like this:

```
$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2013-04-10", "2013-04-12"), 0, 'year');
```

it works fine. But I wanna call it with `$dates` that are returned in `date_range` function,
like this:
`$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("$dates"), 0, 'year');` but it doesn't work. I tried without quotes but it also didn't work. I don't know where is the problem, `$dates` are supposed to be the same thing written like that or like "2013-04-10".
(`print $dates` looks like this: `"2013-05-22","2013-05-23","2013-05-24"`)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You know you provide the $dates data in another array right?

Answer (score 2):

`$date_array` is an array, so:

```
$myCalendar->setSpecificDate($date_array, 0, 'year');
```

To drive the point home more, you want *the return value of `date_range`*, as is:

```
$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(date_range($ci, $co), 0, 'year');
```